# problem with package shape_msgs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

common_msgs: actionlib_msgs | diagnostic_msgs | geometry_msgs | nav_msgs | sensor_msgs | shape_msgs | stereo_msgs | trajectory_msgs | visualization_msgs

```
rosws set common_msgs --git https://github.com/ros/common_msgs.git
rosws update commomn_msgs
```

the package shape_msgs, I have included it in my stack but, "rospack find" is not finding that package.

Robot_self_filter package has a dependency on the shape_msgs package.

so when i try to launch

```
roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch
```

it is showing the following error:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [robot_self_filter/self_filter]: Cannot locate node of type [self_filter] in package [robot_self_filter]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51172/problem-with-package-shape_msgs/) by [muin028](https://answers.ros.org/users/2804/muin028/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-12-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-28**:
Please read the [support guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support). Be specific and at least include steps to reproduce the error, your ROS version and Linux distro. Please always tag your questions appropriately and don't retype commands/erros but copy-paste them (there's a typo in a rosws command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't mention building anything.  The executables cannot be run without building them first.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0